# include common headers and footers

Tags: python, django

instead of writing a common header and footer like CSS, scripts etc in every template, how can I attach templates with common header and footer files.

Comment: I tried with include and extend in <head>, I was not much sure about the syntax.

Comment: So what went not like you expected?

Comment: What did you find out when you looked in the documentation for `include` and `extends`?..

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend both a header and a footer from a html template, 
you should have both header/footer in the same file, and add a jinja block for each place where you would like to add content. (You should really read some documentation first though)

Then, in the specific page, you start with `{% extends "base.html" %}` where base is your template, and you write each of your block specific to this page.

Here is an example of this :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
      Welcome to my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```